# what are the three parameters of bokeh's resize_width_height

Tags: bokeh

the plot.resize_width_height(true, true, true) in bokeh function has three boolean parameters. I think first is resize width, second resize height, but what is the third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The arguments are: use width, use height, maintain aspect ratio

From the [bokeh](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) examples [embed_responsive_width_height.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_responsive_width_height.py#L51):

```
var plotresizer = function() {
    // arguments: use width, use height, maintain aspect ratio
    plot.resize_width_height(true, true, true);
};
```